# Determine type to map to based ob property value

Tags: c#, automapper

Normally, you configure Automapper to map from type A to type B. I need automapper to map to either type B or type C, depending on a property value in type A. I also need to map back from type B or type C to type A.

**Proposed solutions so far is to define two type mapping (A => B, A => C) and call correct mapping in custom if/switch contruct depending on the discriminator. Mapping nesting types, this solution does not work, because the superior mapping will be called then.**

As an example, type Animal is mapped to either a cat or a dog depending on the AnimalType value of the animal.

I need also the way back from either cat or dog, which should be simple, because here I can define 2 fixed relationships (dog => animal, cat => animal).

Can mapping animal => either dog or cat be defined? If so, how?

```
    public enum EAnimalType
    {
        Cat = 1,
        Dog = 2
    }

    public class Animal
    {
        public EAnimalType AnimalType { get; set; }

        public int Age { get; set; }
    }

    public abstract class AnimalDto
    {
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }

    public class CatDto : AnimalDto {}

    public class DogDto : AnimalDto {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the mapping on the base types. This mapping uses `ConstructUsing` to instantiate the correct child DTO by calling the applicable child mapping. Tested with AutoMapper 3.0.

```
CreateMap<Animal, AnimalDto>()
      // create DTO by dispatching to child type mappings
      .ConstructUsing((animal, context) => {
           switch (animal.AnimalType) {
               case EAnimalType.Dog:
                   return context.Mapper.Map<DogDto>(animal);
               case EAnimalType.Cat:
                   return context.Mapper.Map<CatDto>(animal);
               default:
                   throw new NotSupportedException(
                       $"Animal Type '{animal.AnimalType}' is not supported."
                   );
           }       
       })
      // map members of base type
      .ForMember(dto => dto.Age, o => o.MapFrom(ent => ent.Age));

      // mappings for child types, will handle dispatch from base type
      CreateMap<Animal, DogDto>()
           .ForMember(dto => dto.Age, o => o.Ignore()) // already mapped from base type 
           .ForMember(dto => dto.DogSpecific, o => o.MapFrom(dog => dog.DogSpecific));

      CreateMap<Animal, CatDto>()
           .ForMember(dto => dto.Age, o => o.Ignore()); // already mapped from base type
```

For this to work, the mappings `Animal, DogDto` and `Animal, CatDto` must be accessible by the AutoMapper used in the `Animal, AnimalDto` config (e.g. defined in the same AutoMapper profile).

Comment: Thank you. I will use the ConstructUsing. My unit test succeeded also.

Minor change:

This:

      CreateMap<Animal, DogDto>()
           .ForMember(dto => dto.Age, o => o.Ignore())

Replaced by this:

            CreateMap<Animal, DogDto>()
                .IncludeBase<Animal, AnimalDto>();

Comment: This should really be documented right here: https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Mapping-inheritance.html#runtime-polymorphism

Answer (score 0):

Using a type converter, it is possible to map from a to b or c. This works, because inside the type converter I define the mapping instruction myself. Draw-back: mapping is defined manually by hand and must be updated if e.g. a property is added to a class.

Maybe better solution exists?

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void VerifyMappingsSecuritiesModule()
    {
        // Arrange
        Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.CreateMap<Animal, AnimalDto>().ConvertUsing<TypeTypeConverter>();
            });

        var expectedAge = 10;
        var animal = new Animal { Age = expectedAge, AnimalType = EAnimalType.Cat };

        // Act
        var catDto = Mapper.Map<Animal, AnimalDto>(animal);

        // Assert
        Assert.IsInstanceOfType(catDto, typeof(CatDto));
        Assert.AreEqual(expectedAge, catDto.Age);
    }

    public class TypeTypeConverter : ITypeConverter<Animal, AnimalDto>
    {
        public AnimalDto Convert(ResolutionContext context)
        {
            var animal = (Animal)context.SourceValue;

            if (animal.AnimalType == EAnimalType.Cat) { return new CatDto { Age = animal.Age }; }
            else { return new DogDto { Age = animal.Age };  }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The drawback here is that you have to map the members by hand, instead of falling back to an already defined mapping config. I guess you could call `Mapper.Map<DogDto>(animal);` instead of  `new DogDto { Age = animal.Age };`.